# Overlapping LinearLayouts In ScrollView

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-scrollview

I can't see to find a way to prevent the lowest LinearLayout from being cut off within the Scroll View. I have tried adding weightsum and ensuring the Notes section (@+id/etNotes)stretches and fills the screen depending on the height of the device, however, it appears to be cutting off (@+id/bPhot) and (@+id/bHelp) How can we ensure all elements are shown even on small screens?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:orientation="vertical" 
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:gravity="center_vertical">        

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvDetails"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@color/yellow"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/seventeen" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="10dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <RadioGroup
                                android:id="@+id/rgStatus"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="right"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/radio0"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="46dp"
                                    android:checked="false"
                                    android:text="Option1"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/twentysize" />

                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/radio1"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                                    android:text="Option2"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/twentysize" />

                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/radio2"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="46dp"
                                    android:checked="true"
                                    android:text="Option3"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/twentysize" />

                            </RadioGroup>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="10dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical" >
                            </LinearLayout>

                                    <LinearLayout
                                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                                    android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                                                    android:weightSum="5"                       
                                                    android:orientation="vertical">

                                                <LinearLayout
                                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                                    android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                                                    android:padding="10dp" >

                                                <EditText
                                                    android:id="@+id/etNotes"
                                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                                    android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                                                    android:ems="10"
                                                    android:gravity="top"  
                                                    android:hint="Notes (optional)"
                                                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                                                    android:padding="5dp" />

                                                </LinearLayout>

                                                <LinearLayout
                                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                                    android:layout_weight="2"
                                                    android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                                                    android:gravity="bottom"
                                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                                    android:padding="8dp" >

                                                    <Button
                                                        android:id="@+id/bPhoto"
                                                        android:layout_width="45dp"
                                                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                                                        android:layout_weight=".02"
                                                        android:background="@drawable/camera"
                                                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

                                                    <Button
                                                        android:id="@+id/bHelp"
                                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                                        android:layout_weight="2.5"
                                                        android:background="@null"
                                                        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                                                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/sevendp"
                                                        android:text="Check List"
                                                        android:textColor="@color/holobluelight"
                                                        android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen" />

                                                </LinearLayout>




                                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for the parent `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your complete layout revisited:
This portion has been changed:

OLD:

```
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                android:weightSum="5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etNotes"
```

NEW

```
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                    android:padding="10dp" >

                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etNotes"
```

COMPLETE

```
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/svMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDetails"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/yellow"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/seventeen" />

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/rgStatus"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio0"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="46dp"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="Option1"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twentysize" />

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:text="Option2"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twentysize" />

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="46dp"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="Option3"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/twentysize" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                        android:padding="10dp" >

                    <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/etNotes"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:hint="Notes (optional)"
                            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                            android:padding="5dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/whitewhite"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="8dp" >

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/bPhoto"
                            android:layout_width="45dp"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_weight=".02"
                            android:background="@drawable/camera"
                            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

                    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/bHelp"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2.5"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                            android:paddingRight="@dimen/sevendp"
                            android:text="Check List"
                            android:textColor="@color/holobluelight"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen" />

                </LinearLayout>




            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Yes sorry, i forgot to check that! Thanks